# Protractor : Wait for element doesn't work in the 'second browser instance' of a same test

Tags: protractor

I am trying to use multiple browsers in the same test, script fails when i try to wait for the element present in second browser.

```
    var browser2 = browser.forkNewDriverInstance(true);
    browser2.get('https://test.app.com');
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser2.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('.meeting-btn>span')),15000); //Script fails here
    browser2.$('.meeting-btn>span').click();
    console.log("clicked Meeting button");
```

**Error:*

*Failed: Wait timed out after 15010ms*

The element is actually present in the screen but wait keyword isn't locating the element. The script actually works when i write the code in following manner.

```
var browser2 = browser.forkNewDriverInstance(true);
browser2.get('https://test.app.com');
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.sleep(15000);
browser2.$('.meeting-btn>span').click();
console.log("clicked Meeting button");
```

Script fails only when i insert wait keyword. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Do you get the same error when you use `presenceOf`?

Comment: yes, I tried almost all the wait keywords @firstlast

Comment: Try prefixing with `await`:    await browser2.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('.meeting-btn>span')),15000);

Comment: Same time out error after prefixing with await @firstlast

Answer (score 0):

Your error is this line:

```js
    browser2.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('.meeting-btn>span')),15000); //Script fails here
```

Using `$('.meeting-btn>span')` implicitly uses the main `browser` so is equivalent to `browser.$('.meeting-btn>span')`, which can't be found in `browser2`.

To fix the error, use:

```js
    browser2.wait(EC.visibilityOf(browser2.$('.meeting-btn>span')),15000); //Script fixes
```

To avoid this kind of error during developpment, I usually define my `ElementFinder` first, then re-use it. See "targetElement" here:

```js
var browser2 = browser.forkNewDriverInstance(true);
browser2.get('https://test.app.com');

const targetElement = browser2.$('.meeting-btn>span');

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser2.wait(EC.visibilityOf(targetElement),15000); //Script fails here
targetElement.click();
console.log("clicked Meeting button");
```

**To test this code in a new project:**

- follow setup steps from https://www.protractortest.org/#/
- change `conf.js` so it looks like the following:

```js
exports.config = {
    // seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['todo-spec.js'],
    directConnect: true,
    // SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: true
};
```

- create test file `test.js`:

```js
function checkElements(targetBrowser) {
    const targetURL = 'https://angular.io/';
    targetBrowser.get(targetURL);

    const targetSelector = 'a.button.hero-cta.no-print';
    const targetElem = targetBrowser.$(targetSelector);

    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    targetBrowser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(targetElem),15000); //Script fails here
    targetElem.click();

    // title is present
    const titleElem = targetBrowser.$("#getting-started-with-angular");
    expect(titleElem.getText()).toEqual('Getting started with Angular');
}

describe('angular homepage', function() {
    it('test with browser', function() {
        checkElements(browser);
    });

    it('test with 2nd browser', function() {
        const browser2 = browser.forkNewDriverInstance(true);
        checkElements(browser2);
    });
});
```

- add another `it` method with the code from this answer:

```js
it('MY TEST', function() {
    var browser2 = browser.forkNewDriverInstance(true);
    browser2.get('https://test.app.com');

    const targetElement = browser2.$('.meeting-btn>span');

    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser2.wait(EC.visibilityOf(targetElement),15000); //Script fails here
    targetElement.click();
    console.log("clicked Meeting button");
});
```

- run protractor: "protractor conf.js"

Comment: Thanks for your idea of using **browser.$('.meeting-btn>span')**. It helped me resolving an other error that i was facing, but it dint really help resolving the wait issue. Script keeps on failing with ** Failed: script timeout** error in browser2 when trying to wait for an element.

Comment: Did you try the `checkElement` tests from my example? It could give more info to help you