# Protractor - How to pass variable inside browser.get() function?

Tags: protractor

I have saved a url in config.js file in runtime, now i have my url in "browser.params.tempVar". If i use it directly in script like  `browser2.get(browser.params.tempVar);` it is not working, Could someone suggest how to use variable in browser.get() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is the correct way.

Double check that you've got the param set up correctly in config.js:

```js
exports.config = {
    ...
    params: {
        ...
        tempVar: "tempVar"
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Then use the default protractor browser to retrieve the value:

```js
...
const prot = require("protractor");
const browser = prot.browser;
const myParam = browser.params.tempVar;
browser2.get(myParam);
```

or in TS:

```js
...
import {browser} from 'protractor';
const myParam = browser.params.tempVar;
browser2.get(myParam);
```

Could can also override this param value by command-line argument if needed:
Normal run:

`npx protractor conf.js`

Override param:

`npx protractor conf.js --params.tempVar="newVar"`

Comment: yes, i have set up param correctly in config.js.  I entered the code in following way and got **Cannot find module 'protractor'** error in console..                                                    const prot = require("protractor");
        const browser = prot.browser;
        const myParam = browser.params.tempVar;
        var browser2 = browser.forkNewDriverInstance(true);
        browser2.get(myParam);

Comment: Given the code from your post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70592588/protractor-wait-for-element-doesnt-work-in-the-second-browser-instance-of-a, you don't need the 2 first lines from my JS example (or 1st line from my TS example)